# solr - dont show facets if numFound == facetCount

Tags: solr

In our application we use facets to reduce the number of hits. We have a gui like this:

=== Document Type ===

```
[ ] Word (42)
[ ] PDF  (96)
[ ] Excel(11)
[ ] HTML (63)
```

The problem is that I don't want to show the PDF entry when numFound is 96. Cause when the user hits PDF, it wouldn't reduce the results. I know I can parse the response and compare them, but I would prefer a facet parameter that excludes me the PDF entry.

Comment: 1) What should happen when user clicks on Excel (11) ?  2) Can user click on more than one facet?

Comment: It hard to answer your questions without clear details.

Comment: 1) If the user clicks on Excel (11), then the 11 objects are displayed and the facet list only contains the "[x] Excel (11)" facet. If the user clicks again on "[x] Excel (11)" then the facet "filter" is removed. 2) he can click on more than one facet, but it has to be a separate facet list e.g. "file size" or something else

Comment: ok then you need to add fq=filetype:Excel , if your field name is "filetype".  am i missing something? can you copy paste your field definition for this facet.

Comment: Hi arun, thanks for your time. After thinking about my problem again (and writing the comments here), I think there is no way of solr doing this right for me, I have to do it in my application.